# Codea vertices draw full screen

Tags: lua, codea

So I've written a shader that I want to draw across the whole screen of my Codea app, although I have supplied 4 varying vec2's as the vertices table it only draws a triangle. **Why is this happening?**

Here's my code

```
board = mesh()
board.shader = shader("Documents:golBoard")

board.vertices = {vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, HEIGHT), 
    vec2(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
    vec2(WIDTH, 0)}
```

And here's what I get..

[image: golBoard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use:

```
board:addRect( WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT )
```

This adds the necessary triangles to the mesh to construct the rectangle.

[See the docs for more details](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/Reference/Shaders.html#mesh.addRect)

Comment: This is even better! Thanks, I will mark this as the correct answer as it's much better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

So I needed to define 6 points, 3 for each triangle.

here is the new code

```
board = mesh()
board.shader = shader("Documents:golBoard")

board.vertices = {vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, HEIGHT), 
    vec2(WIDTH, HEIGHT),

    vec2(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
    vec2(WIDTH, 0),
    vec2(0, 0)}
```